# Why MathJax not work on repeater page change?

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, repeater, mathjax

I have a repeater in my page that contains mathematic phrases
in first page, it works fine, but when you change page all of mathematic phrases gone
[image: First Page]

[image: Second Page]

best regards.

Comment: See the [MathJax documentation](https://docs.mathjax.org/en/latest/web/typeset.html#typesetting-and-converting-mathematics) for dynamic pages for details about how to re-typeset the page when you ad mathematics to it.

Answer (score 1):

Straight from the MathJax documentation:

> If you are writing a dynamic web page where content containing mathematics may appear after MathJax has already typeset the rest of the page, then you will need to tell MathJax to look for mathematics in the page again when that new content is produced. To do that, you need to use the `MathJax.Hub.Typeset()` method.

Comment: Just FYI, this is for MathJax version 2.  For version 3, you need `MathJax.typeset()` or `MathJax.typesetPromise()`.

Comment: thanks for answer Blindy and Davide, it works for me
Best regards.